# Which Analyzer is used for Solr-Query

Tags: solr

I've added a field-type which uses the EdgeNgramFilter as analyzer to my schema.

```
{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"text_edge_ngram",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" },
        "filters":[
          {"class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"},
          { "class":"solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory",
            "minGramSize":"1",
            "maxGramSize":"4"}
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Further, I've assigned this type to one field:

```
{
  "replace-field" : {
      "name":"MyField",
      "type":"text_edge_ngram",
      "uninvertible":true,
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":true
    }
}
```

I've reindexed my documents but now the following query does not return the expected results. Here comes an example:

`.../select?q=aweso` has no results

But, if I query that single field

`.../select?q=MyField:aweso`, I get 'awesome' as result.

It would be very nice, if anybody can explain what is going on or give me hint how to troubleshoot.

Comment: you need to add that field as default search if you want first query to work

Comment: go to your solrCofig.xml file and check the <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">.... add the     <lst name="defaults"> there

Comment: Default parameter values are specified in solrconfig.xml, or overridden by query-time values in the request. <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">MyField</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

Comment: You can also use `df` in your query string instead of in the configuration (if what you want to consider the default field changes between requests), or if using the edismax query handler, the `qf` argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default search field in `solrconfig.xml` file under `/query` request handler or as `IntParams`
Default parameter values are specified in `solrconfig.xml`, or overridden by query-time values in the request.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler"> 
       <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="df">MyField</str>
       </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I prefer not use the ConfigAPI to update the solr cofig setting and save default configuration directly in `solrconfig.xml` file.

Below configuration is for few request handlers you have defined:

```
<initParams path="/select,/get,standard">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">term1 term2</str>
      <str name="q.op">AND</str>
   </lst>
</initParams>
```

This example SearchHandler declaration shows off usage of the
SearchHandler with many defaults declared.
Note that multiple instances of the same Request Handler
(SearchHandler) can be registered multiple times with different
names (and different init parameters)

Comment: The first configuration: If I do it like suggested the query will ONLY be treated with the 'MyField' analyzer, correct? What if I want to run the analyzer of other field-types additionally? Can you please explain a bit more the second configuration? would 'term1' 'term2' be mutliple fields? (If yes, how can I test this as query string? Why do you define 'q.op'?

Comment: term1 term2 means multiple fields...q.op is query operator...It mean which one you want to use OR operator / AND operator

Comment: Can I test it somehow as query-string parameter? I did not find a way to assign multiple fields to the `df` parameter